# Unity5.6.1f app don't show permissions dialog on Android Oreo (8)

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

everybody!

Unity5.6.1f. App don't ask the permissions on Android 8. Вut you can enable permissions manually.

ADB logcat [file](https://yadi.sk/i/0vAr2WA-3ZXTZC)

On other android versions(5,6,7) works correctly and asks the permissions.

Please, help! Tried to find the solution, but nothing helps.

Comment: What kind of permissions?

Comment: @Hristo In AndroidManifest.xml I have:                                                       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: they stay after </application>  and in ADB logcat I have such problems: PackageParser: Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data at ..., PackageParser: Unknown element under <application>: uses-permission at ...,PackageParser: Unknown element under <application>: uses-feature at

Comment: also I have: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />  after </application> too

Comment: I meant what permissions do you want it to show to the user?

Comment: @Hristo I need gps, location and camera

Comment: @Hristo and external memory

Comment: Have you tried Uninstalling the application + deleting the Data and reinstalling it? Or just clear all data and reinstall. Does the application work as intended or you have to manually enable settings? Have you tested other devices with Android 8? Might be you disabled some permissions on your phone by default.